# How to denote a line and a line segment?

Tags: geometry, notation, convention

[image]

I am certain that the name of the line segment is $AB$. However, what about the line? Do we just call it $CD$?

Comment: According to [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html), $\overline{AB}$ is a segment and $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is a line. (In my experience, we've always used lowercase letters to name lines.)

Comment: When fancy typesetting is unavailable (or adds excessive visual clutter), one can write "$AB$" for the segment *or* the line through $A$ & $B$. If confusion may result, then consistently identify the segment as "segment $AB$" and the line as "line $AB$" (and "arc $AB$" of a circle). Alternatively, assign single-letter names (typically lower-case); eg, sides $a$, $b$, $c$ of $\triangle ABC$ (conflating the segment name with the letter used for its length) or lines $\ell$ & $m$. Note that throwing *too* many varied symbols around may threaten to drown the reader in alphabet soup; seek balance.

Comment: I usually say "AB" for the segment and "line CD" for the line. But different books/people use different conventions.